# SQL ORDER BY with UNION and

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union, alias

I am using SQL in Excel, my query has a UNION statement and I need to order by date.

I have 3 tables: "Work_order_0", "Work_history_0" and "Note_0". "Work_0rder_0" and "Work_history_0" have the same fields.

My code is:

```
SELECT  Work_order_0.WO_Key AS 'WO key',
        Work_order_0.Pos_key AS 'POS key',
        Work_order_0.Order_date AS 'Order date', 
        Work_order_0.Order_time/86400 AS 'Order time',
        Note_0.Note AS 'Note'   
FROM API3.PUB.Work_order Work_order_0 
LEFT JOIN API3.PUB.Note Note_0 ON Work_order_0.WO_Key=Note_0.Relate_key

UNION 

SELECT  Work_history_0.WO_Key AS 'WO key',  
        Work_history_0.Pos_key AS 'POS key',
        Work_history_0.Order_date AS 'Order date', 
        Work_history_0.Order_time/86400 AS 'Order time',
        Note_0.Note AS 'Note'
FROM API3.PUB.Work_history Work_history_0
LEFT JOIN API3.PUB.Note Note_0 ON Work_history_0.WO_Key=Note_0.Relate_key
ORDER BY 'Order date' DESC;
```

As you can see in the last line, I tried using an alias in the ORDER BY clause but it gives me the following error

> Bad field specification in order by clause (7645)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an ORDINAL, so `ORDER BY 3 DESC`?

Comment: `order by 3 desc` Most DBMSes only allow column numbers for set operations (don't know why)

Comment: Oh, sadly it gives me a syntax error...

Comment: And which syntax error?

Comment: _Syntax error in SQL statement at or about ";" (10713)_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's Progress OpenEdge

Answer (score 1):

You can't use alias name in order by in same query

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT  Work_order_0.WO_Key AS 'WO key',
        Work_order_0.Pos_key AS 'POS key',
        Work_order_0.Order_date AS 'Order date', 
        Work_order_0.Order_time/86400 AS 'Order time',
        Note_0.Note AS 'Note'   
FROM API3.PUB.Work_order Work_order_0 
LEFT JOIN API3.PUB.Note Note_0 ON Work_order_0.WO_Key=Note_0.Relate_key

UNION 

SELECT  Work_history_0.WO_Key AS 'WO key',  
        Work_history_0.Pos_key AS 'POS key',
        Work_history_0.Order_date AS 'Order date', 
        Work_history_0.Order_time/86400 AS 'Order time',
        Note_0.Note AS 'Note'
FROM API3.PUB.Work_history Work_history_0
LEFT JOIN API3.PUB.Note Note_0 ON Work_history_0.WO_Key=Note_0.Relate_key) AS T
ORDER BY 'Order date' DESC;
```

Comment: I get a _Could not add the table '(SELECT'_ error :/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  They just cause problems.

Second, do not use `union`, when you intend `union all`.  And table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.  So, I would recommend something like this:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM (SELECT wo.WO_Key, wo.Pos_key, wo.Order_date, wo.Order_time / 86400 AS Order_time,
             n.Note   
      FROM API3.PUB.Work_order wo LEFT JOIN
           API3.PUB.Note n
           ON wo.WO_Key = n.Relate_key
      UNION ALL  -- unless you really want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates
      SELECT  wh.WO_Key, wh.Pos_key, wh.Order_date, wh.Order_time / 86400,
              n.Note AS Note
      FROM API3.PUB.Work_history wh LEFT JOIN
           API3.PUB.Note n
           ON wh.WO_Key = n.Relate_key
     ) w
ORDER BY Order_date DESC;
```

Not all databases require the subquery for the `ORDER BY`.  However, none will recognize a delimited string as a column name in any sort of expression or as a key.

Comment: Well, *Progress OpenEdge*  apparently does allow single quoted aliases :-)

Comment: Ohh okay, thank you for the advice. However, i'm getting a similar error to the solution above: _Could not add the table '((SELECT'._

Comment: @CristinaK . . . Some databases (such as SQLite) don't allow the double parentheses for the subqueries in a `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for aliases and this worked for me.

```
Select count(*) as "Count of orders" from pub.Customer c Left Join Pub.Order o ON c."Cust-Num"=o."Cust-Num"
UNION
Select count(*) as "Count of orders" from pub.Customer c Left Join  Pub.Order o ON c."Cust-Num"<o."Cust-Num"
Order by "Count of orders";
     Count of orders
--------------------
                 220
                8160
```